# What is the best way to save pictures remotely?

Tags: .net, database, ftp, connection

I'm starting a new project in VB.NET and I need make this app connected to a server, initially 10 computers will access/feed the same database. I'm using MySQL to write and read information, but I also need a place to save photos of the clients. Every time that there's a new client, a photo should be taken of that person. Every time a client goes to rent a bike, the worker should search and load its picture.

It is under development, and at this moment the app saves the photo in a web server, via FTP, what makes it slow to write and read. So I'd like to know if there's a better way or service to do that?

Thanks since now,
Erik

Answer (score 1):

A couple options immediately spring to mind:

1. Store the photo on a file system somewhere on the network which all client computers (the ones running your app) have a fast native file system connection to. If the server is a Windows machine, you don't need FTP, use System.IO. Hardware-wise, a network attached storage (NAS) unit is the gold standard solution, but any PC/server connected to the network with a sufficiently large hard disk is acceptable. File access over a Windows network will be quite fast. You then just store your image with a name that can be programmatically determined from the user id or something else in the database, or if you really need to, store the name of the image in the database.
2. Store the photo in your database. You may have to do some research to figure out how to do this with MySQL. It's certainly possible and acceptable to do this with SQL Server, but probably not ideal.

Also, as a side note, it may be worth figuring out why your FTP solution is slow. Is it the network? Is it FTP implementation? Is it some other factor? FTP should be reasonably fast since that protocol was designed specifically for file transfer. So if the problem is with your infrastructure, it may affect any other solution you come up with. What I'm saying is, make sure you're solving the right problem. It would be a shame to invest in re-engineering the solution to find that it's still slow because you have a terrible network or something like that.